# selector crawling no result

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler

I try crawling movie site.
No error, but no result
There's no iframe. And I choose select location 
through chrome > F12 > Copy > Copy selector

Site Link is [CGV movie](http://ticket.cgv.co.kr/Reservation/Reservation.aspx?MOVIE_CD=&MOVIE_CD_GROUP=&PLAY_YMD=&THEATER_CD=&PLAY_NUM=&PLAY_START_TM=&AREA_CD=&SCREEN_CD=&THIRD_ITEM=)

[Element what i select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3GOt.png)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import os

## python file location
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

req = requests.get('http://ticket.cgv.co.kr/Reservation/Reservation.aspx?MOVIE_CD=&MOVIE_CD_GROUP=&PLAY_YMD=&THEATER_CD=&PLAY_NUM=&PLAY_START_TM=&AREA_CD=&SCREEN_CD=&THIRD_ITEM=')
html = req.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
movie_titles = soup.select(
    '#movie_list > ul > li > a > span.text'
    )

data = {}

for title in movie_titles:
    data = title.text + "\n"

with open(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'result.json'), 'w+') as json_file:
    json.dump(data, json_file)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you want is dynamically loaded. Use a method like selenium e.g.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = 'http://ticket.cgv.co.kr/Reservation/Reservation.aspx?MOVIE_CD=&MOVIE_CD_GROUP=&PLAY_YMD=&THEATER_CD=&PLAY_NUM=&PLAY_START_TM=&AREA_CD=&SCREEN_CD=&THIRD_ITEM='
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
data = [item.text for item in WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#movie_list > ul > li > a > span.text")))]
print(data)
```

You can shorten your css selector to

```
#movie_list .text
```

Comment: Thanks. What you teach me acts very well! But can't I crawling without selenium? Why my code not act? I want to know "dynamically loaded" means.

Comment: The data you want isn't loaded by the time requests is done. You need a method like selenium which allows javascript to run on this page so your content is available. I add a wait condition to ensure that data is present. Other pages you may be able to use requests only.

Comment: Your code + options.add_argument('headless') = act very well!!! very thank you. stackoverflow very kind and usefull!